# How can i convert cahracters drawn with draw(rect:) into strings?

Tags: ios, swift, string, fonts, ocr

[image]I am working on a project where I need to draw alphabetic characters using draw(rect:) method. Until now I am able to draw these hand-drawn characters but I am unable to export these characters as strings. I tried to get the drawn alphabets using screenshots and OCR but all other algorithms just detect the test and resample the text to redefined shapes whereas, i need to convert the drawn character as it to the string or ".ttf".

Comment: Your question is both too broad and too vague to be answerable. Does your program draw these pictures of characters on the screen, or does the user draw them? If the program draws them, simply save the source string and use that. If the user draws characters "freehand" then you will need to use some sort of OCR. OCR is especially tricky with hand-drawn characters because of the variability in the drawing.

Comment: Or are you saying that you want to be able to turn your hand-drawn characters into a TrueType font file?

Comment: @DuncanC yes that's right I want users to draw characters then use these characters to turn into and use as TrueType font.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to have the user draw characters and turn their drawings into a font, you have your work cut out for you.

I suggest you have the user draw one character at a time. Since you know which one they are drawing, you know what character you're getting.

You'd record the series of gestures the user makes to draw the character, not the resulting pixels.

You'd then need to convert their raw gestures into a series of bezier curves. Then you'd need to encode those bezier curves into a glyph in the font you are building.

I've never figured out how to generate Bezier curves from points along the curve, since the middle control points for a Bezier curve don't lie along the curve. I've read that it's possible however.

As to encoding the curves into a glyph in TrueType font format, I got nuttin'. I suggest googling it.

Comment: i appreciate your effort and i will definately try things you have said. i ll get back then